# How to calculate deltas between two hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I would like to calculate deltas for my stats. I already tried [HashDiff](https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff) gem to compare hashes.

```
a = {"Lima, Peru"=>"83", "Chicago, IL"=>"35"}
b = {"Lima, Peru"=>"80", "Chicago, IL"=>"40", "Krakow, Poland" => '3'}
```

CalculateDelta.new(a,b).execute

```
b = {"Lima, Peru"=>"-3", "Chicago, IL"=>"5", "Krakow, Poland" => '3'}
```

or even better

```
b = {"Lima, Peru"=>["-", "3"], "Chicago, IL"=>["+", "5"], "Krakow, Poland" => ["+", '3']}
```

I already wrote something like this

```
class CalculateDeltas < Struct.new(:a, :b)
  def calculate
    aa = a.to_a
    ba = b.to_a
    c = aa + ba
    c.group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)]}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
class CalculateDelta
  attr_reader :source, :target
  def initialize(source, target)
    @source = source
    @target = target
  end

  def execute
    target.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), result|
      result[k] = if source[k]
        source_value, v = source[k].to_i, v.to_i
        source_value > v ? ['-', "#{source_value - v}"]: ['+', "#{v - source_value}"]
      else
        ['+', v]
      end
    end
  end
end

a = {"Lima, Peru"=>"83", "Chicago, IL"=>"35"}
b = {"Lima, Peru"=>"80", "Chicago, IL"=>"40", "Krakow, Poland" => '3'}

puts CalculateDelta.new(a,b).execute
#=> {"Lima, Peru"=>["-", "3"], "Chicago, IL"=>["+", "5"], "Krakow, Poland"=>["+", "3"]}
```

Comment: Ohh! You are _Surya_.. :-) Why no name..? :)

Comment: Why? What happened.. Account lock..? ;)

Comment: Why use `map.with_object` when there's `each_with_object`

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
b.keys.each { |k| b[k] = (b[k].to_i-a[k].to_i).to_s if a.key?(k) }
b #=> {"Lima, Peru"=>"-3", "Chicago, IL"=>"5", "Krakow, Poland" => "3"}
```

Note that the spec is to mutate `b`.

A further simplification is possible, but I wouldn't advise it:

```
b.keys.each { |k| b[k] = (b[k].to_i-a[k].to_i).to_s }
b
```

I hear someone objecting that `a[k] = nil` if `a` does not have the key `k`. That's true, but `nil.to_i => 0`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Hash.new().tap{|h| b.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.to_i}; a.each{|k,v| h[k] -= v.to_i}}`

Returns `{"Lima, Peru"=>-3, "Chicago, IL"=>5, "Krakow, Poland"=>3}`

---

**EDIT**
To make this code return only strings in the hash use:

```
Hash.new().tap{|h| b.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.to_i}; a.each{|k,v| h[k] -= v.to_i}}.
  tap{|h| h.each{|k,v| h[k] = h[k].to_s }}
```

Returns `{"Lima, Peru"=>"-3", "Chicago, IL"=>"5", "Krakow, Poland"=>"3"}`

Comment: `Hash.new().tap{|h| b.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.to_i}; a.each{|k,v| h[k] -= v.to_i}} #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'b' for main:Object` This does not produce the desired output anyway. Values should be string not fixnum.

Comment: Well the hashes `a` and `b` have to be in scope to use them... This is what your error tells you. To make Strings out of it: `.tap{|h| h.each{|k,v| h[k] = h[k].to_s }}`